# VS Code does not launch a web browser when starting Live Server or "npm start" with React

Tags: npm, browser, liveserver

I'm using Visual Studio Code Insiders on Arch Linux (installed via snapstore), and whenever I try to "open with live server", no browser launches. I can manually go to the local domain myself and its running, however it is annoying how it doesn't work out of the box. Same thing happens when using a react app, except it shows a link to follow in the integrated terminal.

It's not the biggest of deals, but it is annoying me because I do remember a time when Firefox was my default browser (fresh Arch install) and I was not having that problem.

Maybe I messed up something  in the VS Code user settings but I cant remember... any tips to fix this hiccup would be much appreciated!

*also the same thing happened with VS Code Insiders-git and bin from the AUR. Installing other versions and other repos didn't help.*